# parsing a string as DOM in jQuery

Tags: jquery

normally from an ajax post, I just do this:

```
$.ajax(
    ..
    success:function(data){
        $('#target').html(data);
    }
)
```

But, I would like to do something different, specifically get pieces of the return data and put them in pieces of the target, something like this:

```
//suppose the returned data was as follows:
var data='<div id="replace1" class="transfer">new value 1</div><p>other text here</p><div id="replace2" class="transfer">new value 2</div>';
$(data).find('.transfer').each(function(i,element){
    var id=$(element).attr('id'); //will be replace1, replace2
    //now update a piece in the current document, if it exists
    $('#'+id).html($(element).html());
});
```

Please note, the above does not work, which is why i need your help.  I am still trying to get my mind around how to work with `$(data)` vs. `$('#some_div')`

Comment: Try `$("<div/>).html(data).find(...`

Answer (score 0):

`.find()` searches descendants, but not the top-level element. You need to wrap another DIV around it:

```
$('<div>', { html: data }).find('.transfer').each(...);
```